# Change <td> class with IF condition or hide jQuery plugin editable

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, datatable, bootstrap-4

I have a table and one of the column uses the JQuery Plugin editable and I want to hide it if a condition from another column applies, or it can also be to just hide it if the value of that cell is null.

The table:

```
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.number)
            </td>

            <td class="editSelect" data-id="@item.ID" data-propertyname="action">

                @if (item.number == 1)
                {
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                }
                else
                {
                    item.Name = null;
                }
            </td>
```

jQuery Plugin:

```
$('.editSelect').editable('/path', {
   ...code
}
```

What is the best way to achive this for this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just put your `<td>` element inside your if condition (this way it won't exist if the condition is not true:

```
@if (item.number == 1)
{
    <td class="editSelect" data-id="@item.ID" data-propertyname="action">        
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
    </td>
}
```

if you just want to hide it:

```
@if (item.number == 1)
{
     <td class="editSelect" data-id="@item.ID" data-propertyname="action">  
     @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
     </td>
}
else
{
     <td style="display:none" class="editSelect" data-id="@item.ID" data-propertyname="action">   
     </td>
}
```